# ASP.NET MVC ActionResult POST without Submit

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I am very new ASP.NET MVC, I took an intro ASP.NET months and months ago, and have unfortunately forgotten nearly everything :(

I have been given a task to add a lookup button to a page that takes in a username from a textbox and verifies whether or not that username is valid. 
[image]

[image]

I have spent hours and hours trying to get it to work. Unfortunately what i realllyyy need to do is sit down for a few weeks and re-teach myself and learn javascript, jquery, asp.net mvc. I am going to learn it all, but this assignment is to small and specific to spend weeks learning languages and frameworks just to begin solving.

Here is where i'm at:

Structure of Controller:

```
public class NewUserRequestController : Controller
{
    // GET: NewUserRequest
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new NewUserRequest());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
    public ActionResult LookupLDN(ITFormsLibrary.NewUserRequest req)
    {
        //Code that Verifies user etc
        return View(req);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
    public ActionResult Submit(ITFormsLibrary.NewUserRequest req)
    {
            //Code that handles submission validation & errorvalidation 
            return View("Index", req);
    }
}
```

Now in the view, I have tried messing around with:

```
@using((Ajax.BeginForm("LookupLDN", "NewUserRequest", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "NewUserIfo"}, new { @class = "form-inline", role = "form" }))
```

Only to discover I can't nest forms.

I have tried:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Lookup", "LookupLDN", "NewUserRequest", new { Model},null, new { @class = "form-inline", role = "form" })
```

and

```
@HTML.ActionLink("Lookup", "LookupLDN", "NewUserRequest", new { Model})
```

both of which return 404 for some reason.

I have also tried:

```
<input type="button" value="Lookup" onclick="return lookupLDN()"/>
```

But, I don't know how to construct a javascript statement to handle an asynchronous POST? - Should I even be trying to POST?

If any of you understand what I am trying to accomplish and can provide help, I would be extremely grateful. thank you!

Comment: You can use a `[Remote]` attribute for this - refer [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - The `[Remote]` attribute has to be one of the least known but most functionally awesome data validation tags .NET has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about JSON.

**EDITED** *as per Tommy's comment. Use POST instead of GET.*

> It should be a POST method because you are sending data to the server
>   and asking it to take action on that data (POST) and not just asking
>   the server to give us information without sending it anything (GET).
>   With POST, you can add checks around CSRF tokens, don't have to worry
>   about the Googlebot doing something it shouldn't, etc.

**HTML (VIEW)**

```
 <input type="button" id="btnLookupUser" value="Lookup" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#btnLookupUser').click(function () {
        var vUsername= $('#txtUserName').val();

        if (vUsername.trim() == '') {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
       //URL to your JSON method. (here I suppose you have a LookupUser action method. Change application path the way it works for you.)
         $.ajax({
        url: applicationPath + '/LookupUser',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { userName: encodeURIComponent(vUsername.trim()), 
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {

           //Do your logic based on the result.
            switch (result) {
            case true:

                break;
            default:
                break;

            }
        },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert(xhr.status);
         alert(thrownError);
    })

    });
});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult LookupUser(string userName)
{ 
    //Your logic
    return Json("Whether is valid or not"); //You can as well deny GET   here.
}
```

Comment: I guess I forgot to make it clear in the original post that I was trying to pass the full model from the view into the controller, so that I can validate the username in the controller, set the username to the NewUserRequest object and then return the object back to the view. The JSON there just handles the username itself getting passed to the controller?

Comment: @user3653277 - why do you need the entire model to validate a username?  This solution (outside of forcing you to use GET, it can and should be rewritten to use POST) accomplishes exactly what is needed without any extra information.  If the name is valid, it is already set in the form (the textbox).  If its not, I assume you would set a `valid=false ` flag somewhere to prevent full form submission and highlight the textbox red.  Note - you should check the username again on full form POST as JS validation is very easy to circumvent.

Comment: Thanks for your input Tommy. That's what I was thinking. When I suggested to use a GET over POST, I believe this has to be a GET because he is only validating the username and not posting anything. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Moe - It doesn't really "have" to be either.  But, I stressed that it should be a POST method because you are sending data to the server and asking it to take action on that data (POST) and not just asking the server to give us information without sending it anything (GET).  With POST, you can add checks around CSRF tokens, don't have to worry about the Googlebot doing something it shouldn't, etc.  Just a matter of convention tied with a little personal preference :) (and you don;t have to remember to add the AllowGet)

Comment: Tommy! Thanks a lot man for explaining this out! I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem man! I'll update the answer based on Tommey's comment.